# thinking sphinx search has_many not working no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, thinking-sphinx

**model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :alignment, :description, :first_name, :last_name
  has_many :roles    #table roles with active as one of the field with value equal t or f (boolean)
end    

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :organization_id, :person_id, :position_id
  belongs_to :person 
  belongs_to :organization 
  belongs_to :position
end
```

**person_index.rb**

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :person, :with => :active_record do
 #Fields
 indexes last_name, :sortable => true
 indexes first_name, :sortable => true
 indexes alignment
 #indexes role(:active), :as => :active
 indexes role.active, :as => :active


 #Attributes
  has created_at, updated_at
  has professions(:id), :as => :profession_ids
  has positions(:id), :as => :position_id
  has organizations(:id), :as => :organization_id

end
```

**people_controller**

```
 filters = {}
 filters[:profession_ids] = params[:profession_ids] if params[:profession_ids].present?
 filters[:organization_id] = params[:organization_id] if params[:organization_id].present?
 filters[:position_id] = params[:position_id] if params[:position_id].present?   
 filters[:active_ids] = role if params[:active].present?  #added   

 @people = Person.search " #{params[:lastname]} #{params[:firstname]} #{params[:alignmemt]}", 
 :with     => filters,
 :star => true, 
 :condition =>  {:alignment => params[:alignment], :active =>  params[:active]}, 
 :order => 'last_name ASC, first_name ASC',
 :page     => params[:page], 
 :per_page => 20
```

When i search `active` and/or `alignment` it is not filtering result and doesn't give me error. these are both string field, `alignment` is in the people table and `active` is in another table (roles)

Why? What am i missing?

**update**
Tried the recommended solution for `active` on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374617/using-crc32-tweak-on-has-many-relations-in-thinking-sphinx?rq=1) and same result...

**person_index.rb**

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :person, :with => :active_record do
 #Fields
 indexes last_name, :sortable => true
 indexes first_name, :sortable => true
 indexes alignment

 #Attributes
  has created_at, updated_at
  has professions(:id), :as => :profession_ids
  has positions(:id), :as => :position_id
  has organizations(:id), :as => :organization_id
  has roles.active, :as => :active_ids

end
```

**people_controller**

```
def index
 @role = Role.find_by_active(params[:active])   #ADDED

 filters = {}
 filters[:profession_ids] = params[:profession_ids] if params[:profession_ids].present?
 filters[:organization_id] = params[:organization_id] if params[:organization_id].present?
 filters[:position_id] = params[:position_id] if params[:position_id].present?

 @people = Person.search " #{params[:lastname]} #{params[:firstname]} #{params[:alignmemt]}", 
 :with     => filters,
 :star => true,
 :condition =>  {:alignment => params[:alignment], :active_ids =>  @role}, #CHANGED
 :order => 'last_name ASC, first_name ASC',
 :page     => params[:page], 
 :per_page => 20
```

but still have same result... WHY?

***controller updated after Pat answer***

```
def index   
  if params[:active].present?
    role = Array.new
    rolepid = Array.new
    role = Role.find_all_by_active(params[:active])
    role.each do |num|
     puts num.person_id
     rolepid << num.person_id  #get all the person id whith the params[:active]
    end
  end

  filters = {}
  filters[:profession_ids] = params[:profession_ids] if params[:profession_ids].present?
  filters[:organization_id] = params[:organization_id] if params[:organization_id].present?
  filters[:position_id] = params[:position_id] if params[:position_id].present?
  filters[:active_ids] = rolepid if params[:active].present?

  @people = Person.search " #{params[:lastname]} #{params[:firstname]} #{params[:alignent]}", 
  #:classes => [Person, Role],
  :with     => filters,
  :star => true, 
  :condition =>  {:alignment => params[:alignment]},
  :order => 'last_name ASC, first_name ASC',
  :page     => params[:page], 
  :per_page => 20
```

But now it is looking for active in people table when it should look in roles table. So i added `#:classes => [Person, Role],` but no luck....

```
 Role Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."active" = 'f'
 Sphinx Query (0.7ms)  SELECT * FROM `person_core` WHERE `active_ids` IN (304, 34, 306, 308, 334, 295, 344, 348, 352, 354, 365, 367, 308, 429, 468, 9, 544, 590, 609, 110, 1643, 1652, 1653, 1655, 1669, 628, 1687, 1691, 1709) AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `last_name` ASC, first_name ASC LIMIT 0, 20
 Sphinx  Found 0 results
```

So i **change** in the controller
`filters[:active_ids] = rolepid if params[:active].present?`
to
 `filters[:id] = rolepid if params[:active].present?`

Since `rolepid` is an array of integer with the person ids.
But `Sphinx` is just looking for 4 ids that are not in `rolepid`... I am confused :|

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "firstname"=>"", "lastname"=>"", "alignment"=>"", "organization_id"=>"", "position_id"=>"", "active"=>"f", "commit"=>"Search"}
 Role Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."active" = 'f'
 Sphinx Query (0.6ms)  SELECT * FROM `person_core` WHERE `id` IN (304, 34, 306, 308, 334, 295, 344, 348, 352, 354, 365, 367, 308, 429, 468, 9, 544, 590, 609, 110, 1643, 1652, 1653, 1655, 1669, 628, 1687, 1691, 1709) AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `last_name` ASC, first_name ASC LIMIT 0, 20
 Sphinx  Found 4 results
 Person Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" IN (84, 1, 61, 50)
```

Why is it not returning the 29 records from `rolepid` array ?

filtering for `alignment` IS working. thanks for catching the misspelled word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `active_ids` as an attribute (which, if it's integers, is certainly appropriate), then it should be a filter in the `:with` option, not in the `:conditions` option.

I'm not sure if this is related, but it's worth noting you've misspelled alignment in the query string (you've got alignmemt instead).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am still stuck... 1) i used :with for active attribute which is an array of integers, but no luck.   2) regarding alignment corrected the misspelled world but nothing either....

Comment: 2)`alignment` was misspelled twice. it is working now. Thanks

Comment: got answer i had to use sphinx_internal_id, so i removed `filters[:id] = rolepid if params[:active].present?` and replace it by `filters[:sphinx_internal_id] = rolepid` . for more explanation go here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/thinking-sphinx/NwsMsN7ozpU